# Extract Digits from String

Tags: python, regex, string, selenium, extract

I'm trying to extract digits from a unicode string. The string looks like `raised by 64 backers` and `raised by 2062 backers`. I tried many different things, but the following code is the only one that actually worked.

```
backers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text
match = re.search(r'(\d+)', backers)
print(match.group(0))
```

Since I'm not sure how often I'll need to extract substrings from strings, and I don't want to be creating tons of extra variables and lines of code, I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to accomplish this?

I know I could do something like this.

```
def extract_digits(string):
    return re.search(r'(\d+)', string)
```

But I was hoping for a one liner, so that I could structure the script without using an additional function like so.

```
backers = ...
title = ...
description = ...
...
```

Even though it obviously doesn't work, I'd like to do something similar to the following, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)
```

And the output looks like this.

`<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000542FD50>`

**Any way to deal with this?!**

Comment: where are `title` and `description` coming from? It'd be better if you can give some input and expected output.

Comment: @AshishAcharya you don't need to worry about `title` and `description`, that was to simply show how i'd like to structure my code without the use of an additional function, ideally

Comment: @Anthony, What about Regex `raised by (.*) backers` to extract only digit ? may be like `import re
re.match(r"raised by (.*) backers", string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option you can skip using regex and use built-in Python [`isdigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) (no additional imports needed):

```
digit = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()][0]
```

Comment: Why doesn't `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)[0]` or `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)(0)` or something like that work, but yours does and the other buddy's whose answer is so similar to that?

Comment: AFAIK `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)[0]` actually should work also...

Comment: @Andersson No it should be `group(0)` in the end, please check my answer

Comment: i'm gonna try `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text).group(0)` tomo when i wake up n c if that works!

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov , `[0]` should work as well

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov it doesn't. i get a `TypeError`

Comment: i actually prefer this answer because then i don't need to import yet another module

Comment: hey, would you mind breaking down the syntax for me? `for sub in browser.element.text.split()` obviously breaks the string up into chunks where there are spaces and creates a list of the items. the very first `sub` is what is returned `if sub.isdigit()`??? also, how come you have to contain it all in a list???

Comment: Yeah, it breaks the string into list of sub-strings and check each sub-string in list. If it's a digit `sub.isdigit()` returns `True` - the sub-string is added to new list. If there are more than one digit in a string and you want to get all of them in a list - simply remove element index as `digits = [sub for sub in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.split() if sub.isdigit()]`

Comment: @Anthony it is your choice to mark an answer you like. Andersson has provided a good answer, which I have of course upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
number = backers.findall(r'\b\d+\b', 'raised by 64 backers')
```

output:

```
64
```

So the method could be like this:

```
def extract_digits(string):
    return re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string)
```

**DEMO** [here](http://regexr.com/3s22d)

**EDIT:** since you want everything in one line, try this:

```
import re

backers = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)[0]
```

PS:

search ⇒ find something anywhere in the string and return a [match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) object
findall ⇒ find something anywhere in the string and return a list.

**Documentation:**

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

Documentation link: [docs.python.org/2/library/re.html](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

So to do the same with `search` use this:

```
backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text).group(0)
```

Comment: i'll try that right away. i don't need to `import re` for that do i?

Comment: i'd prefer to stick it ALL in one statement, though. something like: `backers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string)` even though i know that isn't a thing

Comment: I think you can do this as well, if it is neccesary to do this in one string. But it will be not very good for reader

Comment: i've edited my question. i tried doing that, but it doesn't work as intended

Comment: the output of `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)` is `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000542FD50>` :..(

Comment: I have edited my code please have a look

Comment: `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000542FD50>` its return a list of elements, so at the end of statement just add `[0]` to get first element. The answer is edited

Comment: i've tried adding `[0]` and even `(0)` to the end of `backers = re.search(r'(\d+)', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@gogo-test="backers"]').text)`, but i get the following error: `TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. i tried yours and it works, but i don't like the idea of using `findall` instead of `search` since there will only ever be one match... why does yours (`findall`) work and mine (`search`) doesn't? explain that in your answer and i'll mark it as correct!

Comment: `search ⇒ find something anywhere in the string and return a match object` and
`findall ⇒ find something anywhere in the string and return a list`.  Docu:

Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string. Documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: yeah i read the docs. so how would i access the substring/digits from that MatchObject?!?!

Comment: I have added info in the answer, please have a look

Comment: i actually prefer the other answer since i don't have to import yet another module